# Material design CSS ripple does not apply ripple effect

Tags: html, css, material-design

I am trying to apply material design ripple effect to a button but on the browser I see no ripple effect applied to the button,

The code that is using the ripple is,

```
btn_ripple = document.querySelector('.mdc-button');
       mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(btn_ripple);
```

I have tried the below but none of them work,

```
mdc.autoInit(); // after the above code
MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));
```

I am not using node for bundling.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="masterCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web@latest/dist/material-components-web.min.js">

       btn_ripple = document.querySelector('.mdc-button');
       mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(btn_ripple);

       mdc.autoInit();

      MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));// does not work

      const foo = new MDCFoo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));//does not work
       </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header">

    </div>
    <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--unelevated" style="margin-left: 50%;">RIPPLE</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button doesn't exist at the time that the script runs.

Wrapping your script on a `window.addEventListener('load', function(){ [...] })` is the first step to fix it.

Second, you have a `<script>` with a `src` attribute and then with code.
You can't mix both.
Just write a `<script src="..."></script>` and then open a new `<script>` with the inline code.

**Note**: this answer assumes that all files loaded properly.

Answer (score -1):

Add matRipple in button tag and import MatRippleModule,
You also change the MatRippleColor

eg:

```
<button matRipple [matRippleColor]="'#cad1f7'">RIPPLE</button>
```